# Retrieving variable from other class NOT working

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Can I get the variable from another class if I do it like this :

---------------------------- HelloWorldLayer.h -------------------------------

```
@interface HelloWorldLayer : CCLayer
{  

...
BOOL win;
...
}

@property (nonatomic,readwrite) BOOL win;
```

---------------------------- HelloWorldLayer.m -------------------------------

```
@synthesize win;

-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  if (...){

  //do something with with variable win ----> IN <---- if statement
  win = YES;
  }
//win is changed only in if statement
}
```

---------------------------- LevelDone.m -------------------------------

```
-(void)nextLevel:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"next level");

    HelloWorldLayer *obj = [[HelloWorldLayer alloc]init];
    if (obj.win==YES){
        NSLog(@"win = YES");
    }else {
        NSLog(@"win = NO");
    }
    win = NO;
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] popScene];

}
```

Can I first get and set the variable `win` here, so that the other class now has the win variable assigned with `NO` or is the assignment of win in the if statement not globally handled ?

if I assign the variable `NO` in the `init` method and change it in a function, it will only take the value that had been assigned in the `init` method... WHY THE HELL IS THAT ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I assign the variable NO in the init method and change it in a
>   function, it will only take the value that had been assigned in the
>   init method... WHY THE HELL IS THAT ?

Because you're not using the same object, you're creating a **new one**:

```
HelloWorldLayer *obj = [[HelloWorldLayer alloc]init];
    if (obj.win==YES){
        NSLog(@"win = YES");
    }else {
        NSLog(@"win = NO");
    }
```

Every time you run this line of code:

```
HelloWorldLayer *obj = [[HelloWorldLayer alloc]init];
```

… you create a new instance of HelloWorldLayer. It will run the code that's in the init method because you're sending it the `init` message. That is why whatever value you set in the init method will be logged by the above code.

What you want is to access the **existing** instance of HelloWorldLayer, not creating new instances of the class. I believe @Jeremy has given you a satisfactory solution for this. Another way would be to turn the HelloWorldLayer class into a singleton.

Comment: Thank you. I thought of that before, but I was (erroneously) told that I actually would be able to access them.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to consider using a protocol.  This way, LevelDone will be notified whether or not HelloWorldLayer has won. Especially if, perhaps, HelloWorldLayer is a long process and running asynchronously.  Here is a rough example:

**HelloWorldLayer.h**

```
@protocol HelloWorldLayerDelegate
- (void)helloWorldLayer:(HelloWorldLayer *)layer didWin:(BOOL)win;
@end

@interface HelloWorldLayer : CCLayer
{  

...
BOOL win;
...
}

@property (nonatomic,readwrite) BOOL win;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <HelloWorldLayerDelegate>delegate;

@end
```

**HelloWorldLayer.h**

```
@implementation HelloWorldLayer 
@synthesize win;
@synthesize delegate;

-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  if (...){

  //do something with with variable win ----> IN <---- if statement
  win = YES;

     [self.delegate helloWorldLayer:self didWin:win];


  }
//win is changed only in if statement
}

@end
```

**LevelDone.h**

```
@interface LevelDone <HelloWorldLayerDelegate>
    HelloWorldLayer *_hello;
@end
```

**LevelDone.m**

```
@implementation LevelDone

- (void)playLevel {

    _hello = [HelloWorldLayer alloc] init];
    _hello.delegate = self;

    [_hello start];

}

- (void)helloWorldLayer:(HelloWorldLayer *)layer didWin:(BOOL)win {

    //Rather than having a didWin: parameter, maybe you can just check the property of the layer object

    NSLog(@"win = %@", win ? @"YES" : @"NO");


    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] popScene];

}

- (void)dealloc {
  [_hello release];
  [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: ok, thanks very much... One problem : if I put `@protocol HelloWorldLayerDelegate
- (void)helloWorldLayer:(HelloWorldLayer *)layer didWin:(BOOL)win;` before the `@interface` it will not recognize the type `(HelloWorldLayer*)`

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of confusion between using the accessors generated by @synthesize and referring to the instance variable directly.  Try declaring your property like this:

---------------------------- HelloWorldLayer.h -------------------------------

```
@interface HelloWorldLayer : CCLayer

@property (nonatomic) BOOL win;
```

---------------------------- HelloWorldLayer.m -------------------------------

```
@synthesize win=_win;

-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  if (...){
      self.win = YES;
  }

}
```

I think BOOL values always default to **False** so you really don't need to set it in init() unless you want it to default to **True**.

Anyway, now the instance variable is set to _win in your class HelloWorldLayer.  Whenever you want to set it always refer to it as self.win.  That's a safe habit to get into when working with properties to ensure you don't run into memory leaks because when you are dealing with pointers, the accessors generated will release and retain for you.  If you set the instance variable directly you have to remember to release it first.

Hope this helps!